Lightning Page with related and details tabs, deleting related tab won't save
I have a Lightning Page for a custom object.  It has both related and details tabs.  I've been asked to delete related tab.
This is somewhat simple when one uses "edit page".
I've tried saving (and then activating) ...
However, the deletion won't actually save!
I've tried both deleting the 'sub-contents' of the related tab, and not doing that, neither works.
I've used the Save button, and the activate button.
I've tried this multiple times.
I've tried clearing the cache.
I've tried this in both edge browser and chrome.
It just won't save.
IMPORTANT UPDATE:  PER COMMENTS, I verified that there indeed are unintentional multiple clones. It's hard to say if these are even updating; I have to delete them one by one, because there doesn't seem to be a list where I can do multiple deletes. Furthermore, when I try to edit them using the object and then lightning page the place I want to edit (i.e. removing the detail tab) does NOT show up; if I edit using a "Edit Page" from the view screen, it appears to work, but silently creates a clone .... I consider this a MAJOR bug in the Salesforce system; is there a work-around, please?
This is somewhat related to:
Lightning record page updates appear to be saved, but they are not

The thing is, your question lacks specific details. Try adding screenshots of your page, explain what you have clicked and in what exact order. In this state, it's difficult to help you solve your problem because we're missing important details and the problem is too generic.

As far as I know, this appears to be a Salesforce bug ... other possibility is this tab is "required" and therefore not deletable.... as if it were immutable...

I don't think the tabs are required on any objects, not that I know of any. Another thing is that usually you don't have to use "Activate" after saving. There is a chance you've created multiple clones of the page you're editing and you're not seeing it updated because only the clone was updated.

@BartoszŚliwiński This may be plausible.  Still, if Salesforce is making clones that the developer is not aware of, I would consider that a "bug"....

OK I verified that there indeed are unintentional multiple clones.  It's hard to say if these are even updating; I have to delete them one by one, because there doesn't seem to be a list where I can do multiple deletes.  Furthermore, when I try to edit them using the object and then lightning page the place I want to edit (i.e. removing the detail tab) does NOT show up; if I edit using a "Edit Page" from the view screen, it appears to work, but silently creates a clone .... I consider this a MAJOR bug in the Salesforce system; is there a work-around, please?
